# Disabling formatting warnings in JSHint

Tags: javascript, jshint

I've just decided to run my JavaScript through JSHint (using the WebEssentials extension within Visual Studio). I'm getting a whole bunch of warnings about formatting, which fight against the Visual Studio auto-formatting (which I prefer). I'd like to turn these warnings off but I can't figure out how.

I can't see anything in the [JSHint Documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/options/) that relates to whitespace/function formatting.

I also don't get any warning numbers out so I don't think I can exclude by warning:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can go about excluded these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems stems from [JavaScript Code Style](http://jscs.info/)

You can edit those settings from the Web Essentials menu, then select the Edit Global JSCS settings option. (I hope. I've never even opened Visual Studio in my life).

You can read up on the rules [here](http://jscs.info/rules.html)

Comment: Unfortunately JSCS seems to stop working almost regardless of the change I make (it doesn't seem to like false or nulls). But I still think this is the right answer.

Comment: There seems to be no direct link between error messages in Visual Studio and the exact rule it pertains to.